# Read only privileges

Tags: oracle, permissions

I have created a user and want to grant the user read only privileges on all database schemas. Can I do that using a single grant statement for all 20 schemas.

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly what you want, but it should be close enough.

`grant read any table to username;`

This provides read privileges on **all** user tables and views (but no privileges on dictionary tables or `DBA_` catalog views).

If you want to this only for specific schemas, you need to grant the specific object privileges.

Comment: Granting `READ` is the correct grant in version 12c. Granting `SELECT` is the only option in prior versions, which allows users to lock tables and records.

Comment: Replace `TABLE` with `DICTIONARY` to grant the V$ and DBA_ tables and views against the instance and data dictionary. Note that this is a deep level of privilege since it also includes things like bind variables. For example, if you have a hashed table of passwords, this could expose the inputs to the hashing function used in ongoing SQL statements.